# Subclass cant call public method of parent

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class called `Foo` which implements the interface `Bar`. `Foo` does provide `public` implementations for `Bar`s methods.

Now I have the class `FooBar` which extends `Foo`. Oddly enough I now have to implement the `Bar` interface in `FooBar`. The next thing that is odd to me is the fact that I just can't call `super.barMethod()` in `FooBar` as this throws following error:

> Cannot directly invoke the abstract method barMethod for the type Bar

What makes this even odder is the fact that `Bar` has 10+ methods but I only have to implement 2 in `FooBar`.

Any ideas why this occurs and how to fix it?

---

Code:

Foo class:

```
public abstract class PersistentEnumUserType<T extends PersistentEnum>
        implements UserType {

    /** The persistent enum type */
    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public PersistentEnumUserType() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) findParameterizedType(getClass())
                .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    private ParameterizedType findParameterizedType(
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class clazz) {
        if (clazz == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Type type = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
        if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            return (ParameterizedType) type;
        }
        return findParameterizedType(clazz.getSuperclass());
    }

    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return x == y;
    }

    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x == null ? 0 : x.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names,
            SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        int id = rs.getInt(names[0]);
        if (rs.wasNull()) {
            return null;
        }
        for (PersistentEnum value : returnedClass().getEnumConstants()) {
            if (id == value.getCode()) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown "
                + returnedClass().getSimpleName() + " id");
    }

    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index,
            SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            st.setNull(index, Types.INTEGER);
        } else {
            st.setInt(index, ((PersistentEnum) value).getCode());
        }
    }

    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    public Class<T> returnedClass() {
        return persistentClass;
    }

    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.INTEGER };
    }

}
```

`Bar` interface:

```
public interface UserType {

    int[] sqlTypes();

    Class returnedClass();

    boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException;

    int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException;

    Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException;

    void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException;

    Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException;

    boolean isMutable();

    Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException;

    Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException;

    Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException;
}
```

Current `FooBar` class which should implement 2 methods (`nullSafeGet` and `nullSafeSet`):

```
public class FileTransferJobUserType extends
        PersistentEnumUserType<FileTransferJob> {

}
```

Comment: Please provide the simple mockup.

Comment: probably it's a Polymorphism issue. For proper explanation, please add the structure you're trying on…

Comment: "Oddly enough I now have to implement the `Bar` interface in `FooBar`"  That does sound odd, are you sure the methods in `Foo` that implement `Bar` have the correct method declarations?

Comment: Added the mockup

Comment: Please also add *how* you're defining the instance and the method you're invoking.

Comment: "Interestingly, while doing the mockup I didn't run into the problem I described above."  - so the problem is solved ?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca its all while still coding the class `FooBar`. No instance/invoking involved unless what you can see in mockup

Comment: @SchiduLuca only in the mockup but not in the actual code

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your actual code, which we can't guess from here :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i added the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nullSafeGet(...)` and `nullSafeSet(...)` are not implemented in the abstract class but overloaded : they do not have the same parameters types, e.g `SessionImplementor` instead of `SharedSessionContractImplementor`

Comment: Good catch, thanks. Adjusted the abstract class and now its working as expected